# Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a python package called `mltester` which contains two sub-packages (`actions`, `dialogs`) and a main script `ml_tester.py`, structured as follows:

```
+ <ProjectFolder>
+---+ <mltester>
|   +---- <actions>
|   +---- <dialogs>
|   +---- ml_tester.py
|   +---- __init__.py
+---- setup.py
```

My `__init__.py` looks as follows:

```
import actions
import dialogs
import ml_tester
```

In `ml_tester.py` I do something like:

```
from actions import *
from dialogs import *
```

All works fine when running from eclipse. When doing `pip install`, the following `setup.py` works fine:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="MLTester",
    version="1.0",
    packages=["mltester",
              "mltester.actions",
              "mltester.dialogs"],
    install_requires=[
        "matplotlib",
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        ml_tester_gui=mltester.ml_tester:main
    '''
)
```

But when I remove `"mltester.actions"`, `"mltester.dialogs"` from the list of packages, I now get an error like:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mltester/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import actions
ImportError: No module named actions
```

And I don't understand why listing just the containing `mltester` package is not enough. Of Course I can simply add the packages back, but now I think that I'm missing something more conceptual here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `packages` do not do any package lookup in subtree. Adding a package to `packages` will only include the package itself and all direct submodules, but none of the subpackages.

For example, if you have a source tree with package `spam` containing a module `eggs` and subpackage `bacon`:

```
src
└── spam
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── eggs.py
    └── bacon
        └── __init__.py
```

Specifying `packages=['spam']` will include only `spam` and `spam.eggs`, but not `spam.bacon`, so `spam.bacon` will not be installed. You have to add it separately to include the complete source codebase: `packages=['spam', 'spam.bacon']`.

To automate the building of the `packages` list, `setuptools` [offers a handy function `find_packages`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages):

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Be aware that `find_packages()` will usually pick up tests which is not usually what you want.

Comment: @shuckc this is what the `exclude` argument in `find_packages` is for.