# setuptools: files are missing from distribution

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I would like to upload my package to PyPI using setuptools. Unfortunately only `__init__.py` gets packaged, and files it imports are not packaged. As a result my package is distributed incomplete and fails on import. My file structure is as following:

```
./
./mypkg/__init__.py
./mypkg/folder1/class_a.py
./setup.py
./upload.sh
```

I am using following setup.py:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="mypkg",
    version="0.0.2",
    packages=['mypkg'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

Edit:
The question is different from [Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083553/why-do-i-need-to-include-sub-packages-in-setup-py) in that it looks for any solutions to the problem, and linked question discusses the technical reasons for one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083553/why-do-i-need-to-include-sub-packages-in-setup-py)

Comment: This explains the matter, but answers a different (related) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution was to list the needed directories like:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=['mypkg', 'mypkg.folder1'],
    ...
)
```

Further reading: [Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083553/why-do-i-need-to-include-sub-packages-in-setup-py)