# Absolute import breaking when publishing on PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have a python package I published on PyPI, my file structure is this:

```
- setup.py
- example.py
- ...
- igloo
  - __init__.py
  - ...
  - models
    - __init__.py
    - user.py
    - ...
```

inside the file `igloo/__init__.py` I have this import statement

```py
from igloo.models.user import User
```

When I import the package igloo from the `example.py` file (the import resolves to the folder igloo) everything works as expected, but when I install the package from pip and import it I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igloo.models'` on the import line from the file `igloo/__init__.py`. In both cases I import the package like this:

```py
from igloo import Client
```

The `setup.py` file is like this

```py
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name='igloo-python',         # How you named your package folder (MyLib)
    packages=['igloo'],   # Chose the same as "name"
    version='0.9.3',
    license='MIT',
    description='Python client for igloo',
    author='Igloo Team',
    author_email='hello@igloo.ooo',
    url='https://github.com/IglooCloud/igloo_python',  
    download_url='https://github.com/IglooCloud/igloo_python/archive/v_09.tar.gz',
    keywords=['iot', 'igloo'],
    install_requires=[
        'requests', 'asyncio', 'pathlib', 'websockets', 'aiodataloader'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development ',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License  ',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    ],
)
```

I also tried replacing the import in `igloo/__init__.py` with

```py
from .models.user import User
```

the same error pops up also in this case.

Comment: do you have an absolute import in your models.py file?  Try running python with the `-v` flag to check import order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083553/why-do-i-need-to-include-sub-packages-in-setup-py)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetup.py%5D+list+all+subpackages

Comment: `packages=['igloo', 'igloo.models'],`