# How to write the accurate "setup.py"(entry_points) when I want to generate multiple command-line applications from sub package and in a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, setuptools

I want to write a small personal package based on the tutorial: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/ .
The structure of the directory is showed here:

```
python-cmdline-bootstrap/
├── docs
├── test
├── bootstrap
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── bootstrap.py
│   └── stuff.py
├── bootstrap-runner.py
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

I further add a new module (`src`) and script (`case.py`) under bootstrap fold like this:

```
python-cmdline-bootstrap/
...
├── bootstrap
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── bootstrap.py
│   ├── stuff.py
│   ├── src
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── case.py
├── bootstrap-runner.py
...
```

the content of `case.py` showed below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse


def case():
    print("This a new command.")
```

I add the following lines into the setup.py:

```
console_scripts = """
[console_scripts]
bootstrap = bootstrap.bootstrap:main
cccase = bootstrap.src.case:case
"""
```

When I execute `python setup.py install` and run `cccase` in the terminal after installation, it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chxp/tmp/python3-test/bin/cccase", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cmdline-bootstrap==0.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'cccase')()
  File "/home/chxp/tmp/python3-test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/chxp/tmp/python3-test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/chxp/tmp/python3-test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/chxp/tmp/python3-test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap.src'
```

It works fine if I use `./bootstrap-runner.py` or `python -m bootstrap`, I think it may the mistake in the `setup.py`.
Thus, how do I revise the setup.py? I want to generate different command-line applications in a python package.

Meanwhile, how do I test multiple command-line applications by using `./bootstrap-runner.py` or `python -m bootstrap` in a single run.
It seems I need to change the content in `__main__.py` or `bootstrap-runner.py` to test each command-line application, such as `bootstrap`, `cccase`.

The original scripts are upload at " https://gitee.com/chxp/python-cmdline-bootstrap " and download by `git clone https://gitee.com/chxp/python-cmdline-bootstrap.git`.

Thanks for your help.

I saw the explanations here: [Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083553/why-do-i-need-to-include-sub-packages-in-setup-py) . It perfectly answer my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution! It seems parameter of `packages` in function `setup` could not recongnize the sub module if you specify the `packages`.

So the following changes will work:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="cmdline-bootstrap",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points=console_scripts,
    version=version,
    description="Python command line application bare bones template.",
    long_description=long_descr,
    author="Jan-Philip Gehrcke",
    author_email="jgehrcke@googlemail.com",
    url="http://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application",
)
```

Just replace the `packages=["bootstrap"]` by using `packages=find_packages()`.

But I still do not know how to really explain the problem and what I need to do if I still want to use `packages=["bootstrap"]`.

Comment: If you don't use `find_packages`, you have to list all packages yourself. `packages=["bootstrap", "bootstrap.src"]` etc. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/50083553/2650249 for details.

Comment: Thank you! I really know what the problem is.